# Compiling android Kernel

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been in phase of compiling android kernel to install module on emulator. But i am stuck with horrible error. Here is how I am compiling the code:

```
>> PATH=$PATH:/home/user/mydroid/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-

>> make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- ARCH=arm

============================================

PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP

PLATFORM_VERSION=AOSP

TARGET_PRODUCT=full

TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng

TARGET_SIMULATOR=

TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release

TARGET_BUILD_APPS=

TARGET_ARCH=arm

TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv5te

HOST_ARCH=x86

HOST_OS=linux

HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER

============================================

- - - - - 

prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -mthumb-interwork -Ibionic/libc/private -Ibionic/libc/private -o out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -c bionic/libc/arch-arm/bionic/crtbegin_dynamic.S

Assembler messages:

Fatal error: Invalid -march= option: `armv5te'

make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o] Error 1

----end-----
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should accept Delan's answer by clicking the hollow check.

Comment: Hi Sam, I got the same problem, could you tell how you resolved it? thanks!

I am compiling Eclair on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Jacky, download and install toolchain for armv5te. This will solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I met the same problem.
Then I found the solution which maybe a little helpful for you.
You just need to `chmod -R a+x` android the whole project.

So I guess the root cause maybe : some binary in android project didn't get executed.

Comment: you don't have to make everything executable

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile a cross-compiling toolchain that supports the `armv5te` target architecture.